# how to use kafka-streams-application-reset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying kafka streams now. In the process of building my app, I've streamed some invalid events, which are now causing exceptions in deserialization.

I'd like to use kafka-streams-application-reset, as suggested [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/#details), but I'm not sure where am I supposed to get the actual kafka-streams application-reset is to be found?

Answer (score 3):

`bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh` is located in kafka install directory. but do you really need it? for doing "resetting" you could just update `application.id` property to any new value of kafka streams config. still if you use auto offset reset as earliest, reset tool will not remove already existing invalid records. you might need `auto.offset.reset: latest`, but it depends on your use case.

in case you want to just skip and log invalid incoming messages, you could use kafka streams property 
`default.deserialization.exception.handler: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler`